# Why is my PHP form validator script not working?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm just trying to simply validate a field in a form, but for some reason if I don't type anything into the mcHandle field the elseif part of my if statement will not echo out the value of $errormsg.

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div id="mainContent">
<?php
    if ($_POST['submitted'] == 1) {
        $errormsg = "";
        if (isset($_POST['mcHandle'])) {
            $mcHandle = $_POST['mcHandle'];
        } else if (!isset($_POST['mcHandle'])) {
            $errormsg ="Please enter your mc handle.";
            echo("<p>".$errormsg."</p>");
        }
    }
?>
            <div id="donateForm">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <ul>
                        <li><label>Minecraft Username:</label><input type="text" name="mcHandle" value=""></li>
                        <li><label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstName" value=""></li>
                        <li><label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastName" value=""></li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Choose a plan:</label>
                                <select name="planName">
                                    <option>Donator 2$/month</option>
                                    <option>VIP 4$/month</option>
                                    <option>Celebrity 6$/month</option>
                                    <option>Saint 8$/month</option>
                                    <option>Legendary 10$/month</option>
                                </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>How many months?</label>
                                <select name="planLength">
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <br><input value="Submit" class="submit" type="submit">
                            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitted">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: `Why isn't it not working`? Do you mean `Why isn't it working`??

Comment: Alvin, I already edited it for Marc ;-)

Comment: Read the docs for [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) and your question will be answered -- specifically Example #1.

Comment: Yeah, sorry long day. I meant Why isn't it working?.

Answer (score 3):

`$_POST['mcHandle']` can be set and have an empty string ("") as its value; that's different of being not set at all.

Comment: <?php
 if ($_POST['submitted'] == 1) {
  $errormsg = "";
  if ((isset($_POST['mcHandle'])) && $_POST['mcHandle'] != "") {
   $mcHandle = $_POST['mcHandle'];
  } else if ((!isset($_POST['mcHandle'])) && $_POST['mcHandle'] === "") {
   $errormsg ="Please enter your mc handle.";
   echo("<p>".$errormsg."</p>");
  }
 }
?>

Comment: I've since written my code to check if the string is empty as well but it still won't echo out the error.

Comment: Never mind this is a dumb post, never code having not slept for a while. Lesson learned!   <?php
 if ($_POST['submitted'] == 1) {
  $errormsg = "";
  if ($_POST['mcHandle'] != "") {
   $mcHandle = $_POST['mcHandle'];
  } else if ($_POST['mcHandle'] === "") {
   $errormsg ="Please enter your mc handle.";
   echo("<p>".$errormsg."</p>");
  }
 }
?> that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's because $_POST['mcHandle'] is set!
Try this:

`var_dump($_POST)`

You'll see how every field in your form is set in the $_POST superglobal.